# Efficiency of moving ball

Tags: javascript, optimization

Here is another example of a moving ball.  I would like to see how to make it more efficient and better. I think that moving the variables to the top of the function would be better but then I tried this and it would not work as good as it did.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CH5EX9: Moving In Circle</title>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);  
function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();

}

function canvasApp() {
    var radius = 100;
    var circle = {centerX:250, centerY:250, radius:125, angle:0}
    var ball = {x:0, y:0,speed:.1};

    theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');
    context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

  function  drawScreen () {

        context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
        //Box
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
        context.strokeRect(1,  1, theCanvas.width-2, theCanvas.height-2);

        ball.x = circle.centerX + Math.cos(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
        ball.y = circle.centerY + Math.sin(circle.angle) * circle.radius;

        circle.angle += ball.speed;

        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    function gameLoop() {
            window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
            drawScreen()    
        }

    gameLoop();
}

</script>

</head>
<body>  
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
   <canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="500">
    Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
   </canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make sure your code works before having it reviewed. If it does not work, head over to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: It does work on this code I tried it

Comment: In my mind, you are duping your questions, the changes in code are minimal between your 3 versions of the dropping ball.

Answer (score 1):

## Your Script

#### Handlers

Unless your handlers are called somewhere else, you can just embed them

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    canvasApp();
});
```

#### requestAnimationFrame

There's this timer function called `requestAnimationFrame` that is better than `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. It's more optimized for animations, aiming 60fps when possible. But it's prefixed in other browsers, check for compatibility first.

```
(function gameLoop() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    drawScreen();
    // All other loop functions here
}());
```

#### Common gotchas in JS

- Never forget semi-colons, even when JS allows you to forget them.
- Remember using `var` when declaring variables. Unless you have them in some upper scope, if you forget them, they automatically become globals - and that's bad practice.

#### Conclusion

There was little to go by, but here's what I got

```
function canvasApp() {
    var radius = 100;
    var circle = {
        centerX: 250,
        centerY: 250,
        radius: 30,
        angle: 0
    }
    var ball = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        speed: .1
    };

    var theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');
    var context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

    function drawScreen() {

        context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);

        //Box
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        context.strokeRect(1, 1, theCanvas.width - 2, theCanvas.height - 2);

        ball.x = circle.centerX + Math.cos(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
        ball.y = circle.centerY + Math.sin(circle.angle) * circle.radius;

        circle.angle += ball.speed;

        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    (function gameLoop() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
        drawScreen();
        // All other loop functions here
    }());
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    canvasApp();
});
```